# Smooth Shading distorts mesh?

Tags: modeling

Why does this happen to my object when I apply the smooth shader and how can I fix it? I am working with a low poly mesh, or at least trying to keep it low poly but, I would like it to look smooth and not jagged. Each time I use the smooth shader it completely distorts the mesh. Do I need more faces? How can create that without using the knife tool? Thank you for any input.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an edge split modifier.
[image]